# Trigger click on href button with js or vbs

Tags: javascript, button, vbscript, triggers, href

my goal here for my users to be able to access the page they need without having to passe trough 3 different pages and clicking all sorts of button to get there. 
i was able to find on this website how to do it for the http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/esrvc-srvce/tx/bsnss/gsthstrgstry/menu-fra.html website. 
now i'm trying with this website : http://www.revenuquebec.ca/fr/sepf/services/sgp_validation_tvq/default.aspx but the thing is that on the second website the button is not coded the same way so my script doesn't work with it and i don't know how to adapt my script for it to work

here's the script i have that works perfecly fine with the first link

```
Call test
Sub test()
With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/esrvc-srvce/tx/bsnss/gsthstrgstry/menu-fra.html"

    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        WScript.Sleep 50
    Loop

    Set oInputs = .Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each elm In oInputs
        If elm.Value = "J'accepte" Then
            elm.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        WScript.Sleep 50
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

here's the difference:

first site : uses "value = J'accepte"

second site : uses "title="Accès au service", class="bouton_acces_fr" and href="javascript:SoumettreParam('S00047','F')"

so in the script i use "J'accepte" to trigger the click in the website, but in the second one "value" does not exist and i see to "id" for the button
thanx !

Answer (score 0):

> but in the second one "value" does not exist and i see to "id" for the button

```
If elm.Value <> "J'accepte" Then
   elm.Click
```

Would be the simplest solution.